# print div content shows null in jquery dialog created with ajax

Tags: jquery, printing, dialog

I create a dialog contain a table via ajax (it has to be created that way because it is a really complex set of nested mysql queries based on a gathering of many factors generated dynamically plus user choices). It works fine.

I want to print the dialog content so bracket the desired content with a div with id przone.

Firebug shows the div when I use the inspect element tool  - and I can copy the contents of it that way.

However, the printElement plugin which I triggered via a dialog button (as suggested in posts I have searched here) did not work so I have done the simplest check - attached a function to the print button

```
buttons: { 
"Print": function() { var cont = $('#przone').html();
    alert(cont);},     etc
```

That alerts null, so is it possible to get the div content and if so, how. I really have spent ages trying to find the answer before posting this

Answer (score 0):

Create your dialog box after the ajax is successfully completed and your data is successfully loaded to your div with id przone.Do not create your dialog box on document ready function

Comment: Thanks - Actually I wasn't firing the dialog on document ready but the line of thought led to the answer - I was putting the div id przone inside the ajax-delivered code from my understanding of the other posts I had read. Now I have put it on the calling page and suddenly it produces the html as needed.